# Google plus zip extracts as .EXE files

Tags: google-chrome, zip, archive-utility

I went to google plus autobackup and made and downloaded all my photos/movies as zip files. After finish, when I extract the zip files, they contain .exe files and no photos or movies. Anyone know how to fix this?

Btw, I use Archive Utility.

Comment: Feel free to write your answer as a proper answer!

Comment: @grgarside, OK.

Answer (score 1):

The photos are actually fine (they are JPG) but the videos are of the .exe format (well not really). If one opens the .exe files with (for instance) the VLC player, they play fine.